# How to see 2 or more prices in the same pane on Equeum?

Tags: eql, equeum

When I plot the closing prices of two different assets and then put them into the same pane, I just get two flat lines at the top of the pane and the bottom. How can I look at them in the same pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click on one of the lines, and on the drop down there is an option to pin the line to a different scale.